# How to change json field names in bulk

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have some json in a hashmap<string, object> and i’m using ObjectMapper to map it json. I need to change the field names of pretty much all of the values.
ex:
change this

```
{ “field1”:”abc”, “field2”: “xyz”}
```

to this

```
{“f1”:”abc”, “f2”:”xyz”}
```

I’ve read about using Jackson and using annotation @JsonProperty, but in my case it’s just not feasible because i need to change the names of atleast 20+ fields. What’s the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why can’t you change ur inout source? Such large change is unnecessary and taxing

Comment: that’s not an option

Answer (score 0):

If you are parsing this Json with ObjectMapper, after getting intermediate DTO you can apply Mixin and export into String and then convert to required DTO.

- Convert String to **OriginalDTO** with `field1`
- Set Jackson mixin to object mapper

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class FinalMixin {
  
  @JsonProperty("f1")
  private String field1;
}

mapper.addMixInAnnotations(OriginalDTO.class, FinalMixin.class);
```

- Convert DTO that you get in step 1 into String
- Convert result String into **FinalDTO**

Comment: How would i do this if the field names are in the hashmap? I’m referring to “private String field1”

Comment: I assume you would need to convert your map into POJO (OriginalDTO)
```java
OriginalDTO original = mapper.convertValue(map, OriginalDTO.class);
```